# Ag-grid cell editor doesn't show entire React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I want to use a React component in a cell editor, but this cell has a limited height, what doesn't allow to see the entire component.

Do you have some solution to this? Ag-grid should set the right height on rendering react components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next link explains how to change row height.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/